# Retrieving Tree in Hierarchical data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have stored some hierarchical data of categories where each category is related to others, the trick is a single category can have multiple parents (Maximum 3, Minumum 0).

The table structures are:

**category** table
**id** - Primary Key

**name** - Name of the Category

**ref_id** - Reference ID that is being used for relationship

| id | name | ref_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | everything | -1 |
| 2 | computing | 0 |
| 3 | artificial intelligence | 1 |
| 4 | data science | 2 |
| 5 | machine learning (ML) | 3 |
| 6 | programming | 4 |
| 7 | web technologies | 5 |
| 8 | programming languages | 7 |
| 9 | content technologies | 8 |
| 10 | operating systems | 9 |
| 11 | algorithms | 10 |
| 12 | software development systems | 102 |

**category_relation** table

| id | child_ref_id | parent_ref_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | -1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 102 |
| 7 | 5 | 0 |
| 8 | 7 | 4 |
| 9 | 8 | 0 |
| 10 | 9 | 0 |
| 11 | 10 | 0 |
| 12 | 10 | 4 |
| 13 | 102 | 0 |

[image: relationship diagram]

as you can see in the diagram, the relationship is pretty complicated, **algorithms** has two parents **computing** and **programming**, similarly **machine learning (ML)** also has two parents **artificial intelligence** and **data science**

How can I retrieve all the children of a specific category, e.g. computing, I need to retrieve all the children till the third level, i.e. programming languages and algorithms.

MySQL dump of the database: https://github.com/codersrb/multi-parent-hierarchy/blob/main/taxonomy.sql

Comment: I assume you are using MySQL 8.x that can run recursive CTEs, are you?

Comment: if `id` is the PK of the categories table you cannot have two `10` values.

Comment: @TheImpaler - Yes, I'm using MySQL 8.x and id is PK, I fixed that table for you. my bad. i was manually making those tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data structure is fixed with a good PK, in MySQL 8.x you can do:

```
with recursive
n (id, name, ref_id, lvl) as (
  select id, name, ref_id, 1 from category where id = 2 -- starting node
 union all
  select c.id, c.name, c.ref_id, n.lvl + 1
  from n
  join category_relation r on r.parent_ref_id = n.ref_id
  join category c on c.ref_id = r.child_ref_id
)
select * from n where lvl <= 3
```

Result:

```
 id   name                                    ref_id  lvl 
 ---- --------------------------------------- ------- --- 
 2    computing                               0       1   
 3    artificial intelligence                 1       2   
 4    data science                            2       2   
 7    web technologies                        5       2   
 9    content technologies                    8       2   
 10   operating systems                       9       2   
 11   algorithms                              10      2   
 62   information science                     61      2   
 103  software / systems development          102     2   
 165  scientific computing                    165     2   
 296  image processing                        316     2   
 297  text processing                         317     2   
 301  Google                                  321     2   
 322  computer vision                         343     2   
 5    machine learning (ML)                   3       3   
 5    machine learning (ML)                   3       3   
 6    programming                             4       3   
 18   models                                  17      3   
 21   classification                          20      3   
 27   data preparation                        26      3   
 28   data analysis                           27      3   
 29   imbalanced datasets                     28      3   
 50   visualization                           49      3   
 61   information retrieval                   60      3   
 68   k-means                                 67      3   
 71   Random Forest algorithm                 70      3   
 104  project management                      103     3   
 105  software development methodologies      104     3   
 107  web development                         106     3   
 113  kNN model                               112     3   
 132  CRISP-DM methodology                    131     3   
 143  data                                    142     3   
 153  SMOTE                                   153     3   
 154  MSMOTE                                  154     3   
 157  backward feature elimination            157     3   
 158  forward feature selection               158     3   
 176  deep feature synthesis (DFS)            177     3   
 196  unsupervised learning                   197     3   
 210  mean-shift                              211     3   
 212  DBSCAN                                  213     3   
 246  naïve Bayes algorithm                   247     3   
 248  decision tree algorithm                 249     3   
 249  support vector machine (SVM) algorithm  250     3   
 251  neural networks                         252     3   
 252  artificial neural networks (ANN)        253     3   
 281  deep learning                           300     3   
 281  deep learning                           300     3   
 285  image classification                    304     3   
 285  image classification                    304     3   
 286  natural language processing (NLP)       305     3   
 286  natural language processing (NLP)       305     3   
 288  text representation                     307     3   
 294  visual recognition                      314     3   
 295  optical character recognition (OCR)     315     3   
 295  optical character recognition (OCR)     315     3   
 296  image processing                        316     3   
 298  machine translation (MT)                318     3   
 299  speech recognition                      319     3   
 300  TensorFlow                              320     3   
 302  R                                       322     3   
 304  Android                                 324     3   
 322  computer vision                         343     3   
 323  object detection                        344     3   
 324  instance segmentation                   345     3   
 325  edge detection                          346     3   
 326  image filters                           347     3   
 327  feature maps                            348     3   
 328  stride                                  349     3   
 329  padding                                 350     3   
 335  text preprocessing                      356     3   
 336  tokenization                            357     3   
 337  case normalization                      358     3   
 338  removing punctuation                    359     3   
 339  stop words                              360     3   
 340  stemming                                361     3   
 341  lemmatization                           362     3   
 342  Porter algorithm                        363     3   
 350  word2vec                                371     3   
 351  Skip-gram                               372     3   
 364  convnets                                385     3   
 404  multiplicative update algorithm         716     3
```

If you want to remove duplicates you can use `DISTINCT`. For example:

```
with recursive
n (id, name, ref_id, lvl) as (
  select id, name, ref_id, 1 from category where id = 2 -- starting node
 union all
  select c.id, c.name, c.ref_id, n.lvl + 1
  from n
  join category_relation r on r.parent_ref_id = n.ref_id
  join category c on c.ref_id = r.child_ref_id
)
select distinct * from n where lvl <= 3
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pCByWF3wkmsZocp6a9PHfN/1).

Comment: Works like a charm, what changes do I have to make to fetch all the parents of any category, (reverse of current SQL)
Also, how do I remove duplicate records. like machine learning (ML) is coming twice in the result set.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pCByWF3wkmsZocp6a9PHfN/0